# Replacing Text in Word with Currency from Excel

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

First time post, please go easy...
I wrote some code to replace placeholder text in a Word template, with text from an Excel file. (e.g. replaces all occurrences of Business_Name with Buddy's Dog Grooming) The code runs, and replaces everything as planned, but when it comes to replacing the Word text Total_FMV with the currency from Excel of $100,000, the code spits out 100000. Any thoughts on how I can get the text in Word to read $100,000 without the decimals?

```
Private Sub OnSite_Builder_Click()

Template = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\TEMPLATE.docx"
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(Template, ReadOnly:=True)

    wrdApp.Visible = True

    wrdApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    wrdApp.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

'Total FMV
With wrdApp.Selection.Find
    .Text = "Total_FMV"
    .Replacement.Text = Range("C28")
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

    wrdApp.Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you thought about using Mail-merge or is this not an option? you could then format and manipulate the data being replaced as you wanted...

Comment: Try changing the line `.Replacement.Text = Range("C28")` to `.Replacement.Text = Range("C28").Text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  .Replacement.Text =Format(Range("C28"),"$#,##0")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your .Replacement.Text = Range("C28") with:

```
.Replacement.Text = Range("C28").NumberFormat = "$#,###"
```